# nested structure simplification

Tags: mongodb, clojure

in this structure i want to remove that particular column from output **(**:i ""**)**  than is it possible???

like..input is same

{

```
:aa {:a "a_val",:b "b_val"},

:qq {:abc 
        {
            :x1 {:x "abc",:u "ee"},
            :x2 {:y "abc",:i "ee"},
            :x3 {:x "abc",:i ""}
    }   
    },
:ww {:xyz {
            :y1 {:x "abc",:u "ee"},
            :y2 {:y "abc",:i ""},
            :y3 {:x "abc",:i "ee"}
          } 
    }
```

}

but ineed output of it like...

{

```
:aa {:a "a_val",:b "b_val"},
:qq {:abc 
        {
            :x1 {:x "abc",:u "ee"},
            :x2 {:y "abc",:i "ee"}
    }   
    },
:ww {:xyz {
            :y1 {:x "abc",:u "ee"},
            :y3 {:x "abc",:i "ee"}
          } 
    }
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127023/filter-a-map-with-complex-nested-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the (rather horrible) schema that's not doable in a generic way. Your schema does now allow querying on fields in embedded documents because you'd need to know the field names of the higher level documents. In other words you cannot have a query "unset all 'x' where 'i' is empty" because your schema is not appropriate for it.

You will have to redesign your schema to allow for what you need to do. As a rule start by writing down what you need to do with your data, then design a schema that allows the most common usecase most efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Building from your previous question... this does both the original filtering plus the elimination of the deep subelement.

```
user> (defn vvals [m] (when (map? m) (vals m)))
'user/vvals
user> (into {}
        (for [[k v] xx
              :when (some #{"0"} (for [v (vvals v), v (vvals v)] (:i v)))
              :let [v (map (fn [[k v]] [k (into {} (remove #(= (:i (val %)) "0") v))]) v)]]
           [k (into {} v)]))
```

This works, but it's turning into an ugly mess. Maybe consider the advice given by @Remon van Vliet. There is also the [zippers API](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html) that might be appropriate for your tasks.